How to Use try with resource for Prepared Statement getting Exception
Wrote the code to insert batch details in DB but getting the below error
org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement with address: "NULL" is closed.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement with address: "NULL" is closed.

Code Reference
getJdbcTemplate().update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
        public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            try(PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_BATCH, new String[] { "batch_id" })) {
                int index = 1;
                ps.setString(index++, batch.getBatchType());
                ps.setTimestamp(index++, getSQLDateTime(batch.getStartedOn()));
                ps.setString(index++, batch.getStatus());
                ps.setString(index++, batch.getHostName());

                return ps;
            }
        }
    }, keyHolder);

Is this try with resource is causing the issue and closing the connection before it is used by JDBC template?

Yes, of course it is: it is closed before the return. You can’t put this into a separate method.

Do you need to use try-with-resources here? I would expect such an API to handle closing the resource for you.

Yes checked the getJdbcTemplate().update() and it is responsible for closing the connection

try-with-resources can't be used here and getJdbcTemplate().update() API should be responsible for closing the connection
